# Need a little tip on batch files

Tags: batch-file

I'm very new to coding and iI'm having a problem that is probably trivial, but is making me pull out my hair.

I'm using a batch script to automate mounting a VHD, executing a file inside and then pause until the user presses any key, which makes the VHD get unmounted and the script exits.
This is the main batch file:

```
@echo off
set fileVHD=Gord

CD /D "%~dp0"

powershell -command "Start-Process mount.cmd '%~dp0%fileVHD%.vhd' -Verb runas" 
timeout /t 1

for /f %%D in ('wmic volume get DriveLetter^, Label ^| find "%fileVHD%"') do set usb=%%D

CD /D %usb%
index.html

echo "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Press any key to fully close this program.!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
pause

CD /D "%~dp0"
powershell -command "Start-Process unmount.cmd '%~dp0%fileVHD%.vhd' -Verb runas"

exit
```

This is the mount script (Not made by me):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

if "%~1"=="" (
    echo Usage: %~nx0 [vhd] [letter]
    exit /b 1
)
set "vhdPath=%~dpnx1"
set "driveLetter=%2"

if "!driveLetter!"=="" (
    echo Mounting "!vhdPath!"
) else (
    echo Mounting "!vhdPath!" to "!driveLetter!":
)

REM
REM create diskpart script
REM
set "diskPartScript=%~nx0.diskpart"
echo select vdisk file="!vhdPath!">"!diskPartScript!"
echo attach vdisk>>"!diskPartScript!"

REM assign the drive letter if requested
if not "!driveLetter!"=="" (
    echo select partition 1 >>"!diskPartScript!"
    echo assign letter="!driveLetter!">>"!diskPartScript!"
)

REM Show script
echo.
echo Running diskpart script:
type "!diskPartScript!"

REM
REM diskpart
REM
diskpart /s "!diskPartScript!"
del /q "!diskPartScript!"

echo Done!

endlocal
```

When all the files are located in a system path that contains no spaces, everything works fine. But it breaks where there are spaces.
That means that somewhere in the code a path is badly defined by the lack of quotes, probably in the mount script. The trouble is that i don't fully grasp the mount script when it starts using all the "%~...." variable path names.
I had to mix in some powershell commands because for some reason the script wouldn't work unless executed as Administrator.

If someone could give some insight to a newbie, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not use, `('WMIC Volume Where "Label='%fileVHD%'" Get DriveLetter 2^>Nul')`, instead? BTW, there are several lines in the mount script which require double quoting modifications.

Comment: As why, i don't know, i got the command from another source, and it seemed to work, but i don't fully understand it.
Where exactly do i need double quotes ?

Comment: Possibly an important one; `set vhdPath=%~dpnx1` should be `set "vhdPath=%~dpnx1"`...

Comment: Still doesn't work with that modification. Keeps outputting a syntax error

Comment: As Compo said there are several lines, not just that one line. Another one: `if {%1}=={}` should be `if "%~1"==""` and yet another set command: `set "diskPartScript=%~nx0.diskpart"`, all file name variables following the redirection operators `>` and `>>` and also following `type` , `diskpart`, `del` commands. Although this particular condition `if {!driveLetter!}=={}` does not cause any problems you should to stick to the convention and use `if "!driveLetter!"==""` instead.

Comment: @sst Alright fair enough. Took what you said and changed the code (updated in the main post). It still does not run though. I even tried double quotes on `select vdisk file="'!vhdPath!'">"!diskPartScript!"`

The script makes sense to me now, but i cannot pinpoint the problem location.

Comment: The arguments of `Start-Process` may need double quoting along with any escaping to make it a valid command line for the batch files to receive. I would have considered running the main script as Admin and call the other scripts without the use of Powershell (*just to do a RunAs to elevate*).

Answer (score 1):

You need end quotes around your parameters when you change directory, i.e.

```
CD /D "%~dp0"
```

You can also see all of the %~ options by running 'help for' in a console window.  In those scripts it's getting the path or filename from a variable.

Comment: Yeah, i accidentally uploaded a version that did not have full quotes, but it doesn't work even with them

Comment: I'm not convinced you need quotes around the parameter. The `CD` command can work without quotes, even when there are spaces in the parameter.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException, What about `^` and `&` ?

Comment: @sst that's a good point. So at least an opening quote is needed. A closing quote is optional but highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Discovered the root of my problem. 
The path from script 1 was not being passed faithfully to script 2, even using using quotes or multiquotes.

Thanks for all the input guys!